Passing whole object as json using cutom html template from column in IgGrid
I need to send the whole object in json format to the external function. I have already added a custom html template in the column. Function is calling but I am unable to get the data in the function.
Following is the sample code:
{
    headerText: "Action", dataType: "string", width: "60px", template:
    '<label class="switch"> <input type="checkbox" onchange="displayDetails(\'${ ' + JSON.parse(data) + '\');"> <span class="slider round"></span></label>', width: "120px"
}

